# Using a state preserving functor with boost::transform_iterator

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

I have functor which looks like following :

```
 struct Functor{
    //Global statistics for all objects seen;

    Statistics stats;

    Object operator( const Object & obj) const
    {
          //Copy Object
          Object tmp = obj;
          compute(tmp);
          return tmp;
    }


    void compute( Object & obj );
       //Compute on Object & store in Object 
       :
       :
       stats += obj; <---compute stats about the object itself.
    }
 }
```

The functor is used with a [boost::transform_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) in the following way :

```
SomeDataStructure ds;

boost::transform_iterator< Functor, SomeDataStructure::iterator  > iBegin,iEnd;

iBegin = boost::make_transform_iterator( ds.begin(),Functor() );
iEnd   = boost::make_transform_iterator( ds.end(),Functor() );

AnotherMethod(iBegin,iEnd);
```

I have two question with respect to the above code:

1) The Functor is passed by value to the iterator. Hence, I am not being able to pull any value out of the functor even when I use the following code:

```
iBegin.functor().stats;
```

Is there a better way of doing this ?

2) The functor generally populates an incomplete object of type Object. i.e. Computes attributes of the object and stores it back in the object. The operator() expects a const object from inside the transform_iterator class. Currently, I make a copy of the object and populate that and return it. I would like to get rid of this unnecessary copy, So is there any way of doing this ?

PS: Alternative solution are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning question 1) You could use [boost::ref](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/ref.html) of C++11 [std::ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref).

```
boost::transform_iterator< std::reference_wrapper<Functor>, 
                           SomeDataStructure::iterator  > iBegin,iEnd;

auto myFunctor = std::ref(Functor());
iBegin = boost::make_transform_iterator( ds.begin(), myFunctor );
iEnd   = boost::make_transform_iterator( ds.end(), myFunctor );
```

Concerning 2), if you cannot pass by non-const reference, it is better to pass by value and avoid making a temporary yourself:

```
Object operator(Object obj) const
{
      compute(obj);
      return obj;
}
```

This allows the compiler to perform copy elision and may result in less copying. See [this article](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I maybe wrong but does std::ref also expose the typedefs defined in the functor ? The transform_iterator needs a result_type without which I get compilation errors.

Comment: @SamratRoy it doesn't keep the typedefs. If you have C++11 (which you need for std::ref) then you can use `auto`. Of course, this doesn't help if the boost implementation doesn't use it. It looks like you have to implement your own reference-like wrapper.